# Aspose word for Java - acceptAllRevisions() method is not working as expected

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words

I am trying to compare 2 word documents, it is not working for some word documents and working fine for others.

Below is the complete code we are using.

```
com.aspose.words.Document wordDoc1 =  new com.aspose.words.Document(oldDocStream);
com.aspose.words.Document wordDoc2 =  new com.aspose.words.Document(newDocStream);
wordDoc1.acceptAllRevisions();
wordDoc2.acceptAllRevisions();

if(!wordDoc1.hasRevisions() && !wordDoc2.hasRevisions()){ 
    wordDoc1.compare(wordDoc2, "Aspose Word API", new Date());
}else{
    logger.info("Aspose Limitation: Unable to compare docs, it contains unaccepted revisions");
}
```

Below code block is executed successfully **without any exception**, So I **assume** accepting revision is **success**.

```
wordDoc1.acceptAllRevisions();
wordDoc2.acceptAllRevisions();
```

But, `wordDoc1.hasRevisions()` returns **true** which means accepting revision is **failed**.

As a result below message is printed in console.

```
"Aspose Limitation: Unable to compare docs, it contains unaccepted revisions"
```

Could anyone can help on this? I raised the same in official forum as well.

Comment: Please ZIP and attach your input Word documents here for testing. We will investigate the issue on our side and provide you more information. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks Tahir, I am unable to upload here because file hosting sites are banned in my company. Could you please refer the same question in aspose forum - https://forum.aspose.com/t/aspose-word-for-java-acceptallrevisions-method-is-not-working-as-expected/172861/2 and help?

Comment: Sure. Please follow [your thread in Aspose.Words Forum](https://forum.aspose.com/t/aspose-word-for-java-acceptallrevisions-method-is-not-working-as-expected/172861) for further proceedings. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 com.aspose.words.Document wordDoc1 =  new com.aspose.words.Document(oldDocStream);
    com.aspose.words.Document wordDoc2 =  new com.aspose.words.Document(newDocStream);
    wordDoc1.acceptAllRevisions();
    wordDoc2.acceptAllRevisions();
    file.save(newDocStream);
    file.save(oldDocStream);

    com.aspose.words.Document wordDoc1Accepted =  new com.aspose.words.Document(oldDocStream);
    com.aspose.words.Document wordDoc2Accepted =  new com.aspose.words.Document(newDocStream);

    if(!wordDoc1Accepted.hasRevisions() && !wordDoc2Accepted.hasRevisions())
    { 
    wordDoc1Accepted.compare(wordDoc2Accepted, "Aspose Word API", new Date());
     }
    else{
logger.info("Aspose Limitation: Unable to compare docs, it contains unaccepted revisions");
   }
```